# Exception when parsing xml file using Xerces

Tags: visual-c++, xerces

I have the following code

```
    XercesDOMParser *parser = new XercesDOMParser();
    parser->setExternalNoNamespaceSchemaLocation("personal.xsd");
    parser->setExitOnFirstFatalError(true);
    parser->setValidationConstraintFatal(true);
    parser->setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Auto);
    parser->setDoNamespaces(false);
    parser->setDoSchema(true);
    ErrorHandler* errHandler = (ErrorHandler*) new Error_handler();
    parser->setErrorHandler(errHandler);

    try
    {
        const char *const xmlFile = "personal.xml";
        parser->parse(xmlFile);
    }
    catch (const XMLException& toCatch) 
    {
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.getMessage());
        cout << "Exception message is: \n"
            << message << "\n";
        XMLString::release(&message);           
    }
    catch (const DOMException& toCatch) 
    {
        char* message = XMLString::transcode(toCatch.msg);
        cout << "Exception message is: \n"
            << message << "\n";
        XMLString::release(&message);           
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "Unexpected Exception \n" ;           
    }
```

I get an exception in the following line:

```
parser->parse(xmlFile);
```

Windows Xp, visual studio 2008, xerces-c-3.1.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the exception?  What's in the file?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x0000003a in Xerces Examples.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000003a. The file it's just a main file that I use to learn Xerces.

Answer (score 2):

The bug was somewhere else afterall.

Always call `XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize()` in the beginning and `XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate()` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

are you linking using static library or simple/normal library..  I got the same problem with the simple/normal library... Using a static library and defining a Macro XERCES_STATIC_LIBRARY in the project seetings and compiling using Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) run  time library can fix your problem...